# PHP exec() TRACERT.exe how to pass desired arguments to Windows command

Tags: php, windows, cmd, exec, traceroute

I want to remotely execute tracert in a Windows machine with PHP exec(). I have:

```
<?php
    echo exec("C:\\Windows\\System32\\TRACERT.exe");
    echo "<br/>Success!";
?>
```

This does not give me errors and it prints "Success!."
But how do I pass an argument (such as an IP address to tracert.exe and print the result in a variable or array? 
I do not know the syntax to pass an argument that looks like: tracert , etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prefer passthru() as the traceroute output can be watched in browser on the fly, not having to wait until completed.

```
$IP=$_REQUEST['IP'];
set_time_limit(120);
echo "<h1>Traceroute $IP</h1><pre>";
passthru("tracert.exe -h 8 $IP");
```

Answer (score 0):

By default [`exec`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) will return only the last line of the executed command.

You should use [`shell_exec`](http://php.net/shell_exec) as follows:

```
<?php
    $result = shell_exec("C:\\Windows\\System32\\TRACERT.exe www.google.com");
    print $result;
    echo "<br/>Success!";
?>
```

Comment: so, to assign it to a variable, could do $output = shell_exec()

Comment: I am getting a timeout error "Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded" I did not get before. I got "-6 Force using IPv6." before which clearly is part of tracert.exe executing and waiting for an argument.

Comment: It seems that the `tracert` command is taking more than 30 seconds. So you could either increase the time limit in PHP (with `set_time_limit(300)`) or use the `-h` parameter in `tracert` to limit the number of hops (`tracert -h www.google.com`).